# Matching on type level Nat in GHC 7.6

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-families, type-level-computation

My question is probably easiest to explain in the form of an example:

```
type family   Take (n :: Nat) (xs :: [k]) :: [k]
type instance Take 0     xs        = '[]
type instance Take (n+1) (x ': xs) = x ': Take n xs
```

The second instance here is rejected, though, because `(+)`, being a type family itself, can’t be used in the arguments. But there doesn’t seem to be any `Succ` or anything that is usually used for matching Nats.

So, can this be expressed; and if so, how?

**Update**. I notice that the `isZero` and `isEven` functions in [`GHC.TypeLits`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.0/GHC-TypeLits.html) are under the heading “Destructing type-nats”. Are they meant to be used at the type level somehow? I would suspect not… but mostly because I can’t see how to. `:)`

Comment: Right. I just installed GHC 7.6 to be able to check this code, and both issues that you mention in your comments below are being flagged by GHC. Apologies. (I pressed the 'delete' button on my answer so now can't comment on it directly).

Comment: It seems like encoding the termination conditions as arguments might work (see https://gist.github.com/a39ce17ca47798b0f0ef) but it only seems to succeed when n==1. I've tried this on the type-nats branch, not on 7.6, so ymmv.

Comment: The `isZero` and `isEven` functions construct the similarly-named GADTs, which give access to the type-level predicate at the term level. In other words, it's a way to do the matching you want in a regular term-level function, rather than a type function. :[

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a known problem in the current implementation of TypeNats. But it is being worked on, have a look at:
https://plus.google.com/117760254622432568621/posts/iMYU2SMViay

Comment: Google Plus has gone. What is current state on this matter?